# jQuery tree from Json

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to make a tree based on a Json but I don't know how to continue.

This is what I'm tried:

```
var j = '[{"Category 1": ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]},{"Category 2": [{"Subcategory 1": ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]},{"Subcategory 2": ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]},"Item 1","Item 2",{"Subcategory 3": ["Item 1"]}]}]';

var json = $.parseJSON(j);

$.each(json, function(i, object) {
    $.each(object, function(property, value) {
        $('<ul><li class="has-children-'+i+'">'+ property +'</li></ul>').appendTo('#tree');
        $.each(value, function(index, el) {

        });
    });
});
```

Inside `$.each(value, function(index, el)` I should do the subcategories but I don't know how.

Any help would be great. Thank you

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2oc98jy/)

Comment: Please add comments if you are downvoting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a menu function which iterates over, since you dont know that submenus are directly accessible as strings or more submenus or rather you can do it much cool way do a check if its an object put in recursion.

PS: Do not append multiple times in a DOM. Go read about DOM repaint and reflow and document Fragment.

Check the snippet below

```js
var j = '[{"Category 1": ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]},{"Category 2": [{"Subcategory 1": ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]},{"Subcategory 2": ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]},"Item 1","Item 2",{"Subcategory 3": ["Item 1"]}]}]';

var json = $.parseJSON(j);
var tree=$('<div/>');
$.each(json, function(i, object) {
    tree.append(makeMenu(object));
});
$('#tree').append(tree);

function makeMenu(object,insider){
    var li, wrapTag = $('<ul/>');
    $.each(object, function(k,v){
      if(typeof v === 'object'){
          if((typeof v === 'object' ? v.length  : 0)===undefined){
            li = makeMenu(v,true);
          }else 
            li = $('<li class="has-children-'+k+'">'+k+ makeMenu(v)[0].outerHTML +'</li>');
      }else
        li = $('<li class="has-children-'+k+'">'+ v +'</li>');
      wrapTag.append(li);
    });
    return insider ? wrapTag.children() : wrapTag;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=tree></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @CristiPrologue: There were some discrepancy and incorrect HTML with previous snippet. Please use updated snippet

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var j = '[{"Category 1": ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]},{"Category 2": [{"Subcategory 1": ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]},{"Subcategory 2": ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]},"Item 1","Item 2",{"Subcategory 3": ["Item 1"]}]}]';
var temp2 = json2html($.parseJSON(j))
$('#temp').append(temp2)

function json2html(json) {
  var i, ret = "";
  ret += "<ul>";
  for (i in json) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(i))) ret += '<li>' + GetObjectName((json[i]))
    if (typeof json[i] === "object") ret += json2html(json[i]);
    else ret += json[i];
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(i))) ret += '</li>'
  }
  ret += "</ul>";
  return ret;
}

function GetObjectName(json) {
  for (i in json) {
    if (isNaN(i))
      return i;
    else return ''
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/gabgdt3p/2/)